# Recaptcha for CodeIgniter Aauth not Working

Tags: php, codeigniter, recaptcha

I'm rewriting my unfinished program from WordPress to CodeIgniter. I'm using CodeIgniter Aauth as a library and right now, I'm working with the Google Recaptcha included in the said library.

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/magefly/CodeIgniter-Aauth/wiki/10)-reCAPTCHA-usage), all I need to do is place `echo $this->aauth->generate_recaptcha_field();` in my layout. I want this to use in my registration and login page.

Here's content of the aauth.php file:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Aauth Config
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| A library Basic Authorization for CodeIgniter 2.x
*/


// Config variables

$config['aauth'] = array(
    'login_page' => '/login',
    // if user don't have permisssion to see the page he will be
    // redirected the page spesificed below
    'no_permission' => '/',
    //name of admin group
    'admin_group' => 'admin',
    //name of default group, the new user is added in it
    'default_group' => 'default',
    // public group , people who not logged in
    'public_group' => 'public',
    // The table which contains users
    'users' => 'aauth_users',
    // the group table
    'groups' => 'aauth_groups',
    // 
    'user_to_group' => 'aauth_user_to_group',
    // permitions
    'perms' => 'aauth_perms',
    // perms to group
    'perm_to_group' => 'aauth_perm_to_group',
    // perms to group
    'perm_to_user' => 'aauth_perm_to_user',
    // pm table
    'pms' => 'aauth_pms',
    // system variables
    'system_variables' => 'aauth_system_variables',
    // user variables
    'user_variables' => 'aauth_user_variables',

    // remember time
    'remember' => ' +3 days',

    // pasword maximum char long (min is 4)
    'max' => 13,

    // non alphanumeric characters that are allowed in a name
    'valid_chars' => array(' ', '\''),

    // ddos protection,
    //if it is true, the user will be banned temporary when he exceed the login 'try'
    'ddos_protection' => true,

    'recaptcha_active' => true, 
    'recaptcha_login_attempts' => 4,
    'recaptcha_siteKey' => 'my_sitekey', //This is not blank
    'recaptcha_secret' => 'my_secretkey', //This is not blank

    // login attempts time interval
    // default 20 times in one hour
    'max_login_attempt' => 10,

    // to register email verifitaion need? true / false
    'verification' => false,

    // system email.
    'email' => 'myemail@gmail.com',
    'name' => 'Eli Marie Natividad'

);


/* End of file aauth.php */
/* Location: ./application/config/aauth.php */
```

Currently, I show recaptcha based on Google's documentation. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: post the application/config/aauth.php file

Comment: Hi @Exprator! I added the auth file as you requested. thanks!

Comment: the setting seems to be correct, that means the problem is there with your registration in the google recaptcha admin, what url did you registered in the g recapthcha

Comment: this one: oss-dev.forexworld.us

Comment: the page register is displaying the captcha properly,

Comment: Yes because it's from the Google documentation. I'd like to use this: `echo $this->aauth->generate_recaptcha_field();`